# Printable characters in Mac vs Linux

Tags: linux, macos, utf-8, extended-ascii

If I do this from command line on my Mac (UTF-8 in terminal and so is the file):

```
tr -cd '[:print:]\n' < infile > outfile
```

I get a different result in the outfile than I am running the same command on a Linux system (UTF-8 in terminal and so is the file).

What can be the reason for this?

This is a sample character that is still there when running the command on Mac: 
š 
(the character is an extended ASCII character 0x9A/s with caron).
The same character is removed when running the command on Linux.

Comment: Does your file contain a `0x9A` byte by itself or does it have a `0xC2` followed by an `0x9A`? A properly encoded UTF-8 stream should have "\xC2\x9A".

Comment: Presumably the two systems have different Unicode character type databases, possibly due to a bug or due to being based on different versions of the Unicode standard.

Comment: @b4hand, my system says that 'š' is LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON U+0161, which is 0xC5 0xA1 in UTF-8. Peter, there's no one thing known as "extended ASCII". I suspect you're referring to ISO 8859-1, but of course that's a different thing than UTF-8.

Comment: @KenThomases Yes, I was assuming that the OP was giving the right name for the character, but when I looked up the character my research agrees with yours.

Comment: @KenThomases: ISO-8859-1 has the same assignments as the first 256 Unicode ones. The rogue character set is CP-1252, which is like ISO-8859-1 with the C1 control set (80-9F) replaced by printable characters.

Comment: @b4hand, your edit is nonsensical. Either the character is U+009A in which case it is **not** 'š' or it is 'š', in which case it is U+0161. Peter, you need to clarify *exactly* what you're seeing, perhaps by piping the input and output through `hexdump -C` or the like.

Comment: @ninjalj, my point was that "extended ASCII" is not informative.

Comment: @KenThomases Many people are confused between the encoded bytes and the corresponding codepoints. My assumption was that the OP saw the glyph he wanted and assumed it was U+009A because of the byte value. I edited the question to show that intent. If the OP disagrees with that interpretation then the OP can re-edit the question to show the right intent.

Comment: @b4hand, you edited it to read "U+009A (s with caron)", but U+009A is not "s with caron". It's incoherent.

Comment: @KenThomases if that's what the OP believes it doesn't matter if it is incoherent.

Comment: @b4hand: Huh? You changed what he said, you can't blame him. He originally wrote "extended ASCII 0x9A". Now, "extended ASCII" doesn't mean much, be he was probably referring to something like [this](http://www.ascii-code.com/) where 0x9A actually is "š" (s with caron). He never mentioned U+009A; you did that and it makes no sense.

Comment: @KenThomases I've rolled back the edit. If you thought it was so bad you could have done the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the remaining byte is 0x9A, the file is not proper UTF-8, nor is the tool you are using to view it (0x9A is š in e.g. [Windows codepage 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) nor apparently your `tr`.

To properly solve your problem, we would need to see a fragment of the actual bytes in the file.  For example, a file displaying as `åäö` could contain the bytes

```
0xE5 0xE4 0xF6
```

if it's in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (which coincides with CP1252 in these positions) or

```
0xC3 0xA5 0xC3 0xA4 0xC3 0xB6
```

if it was proper UTF-8.  On OSX, an old file could also plausibly be in [Mac Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) which would encode this string as

```
0x8C 0x81 0x9A
```

as well as, of course, a large number of other encodings, depending on the file's provenance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as Karol C has shown below in the `tr` source, it **does not** support Unicode at all, so the behavior on Linux for a UTF-8 file is just not going to work if the file contains any multibyte sequences.

According to [this database](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9a/index.htm), the U+009A character is a **control character** and not a printable character. The name of the character is "SINGLE CHARACTER INTRODUCER". It appears that the glyph as rendered on that page visually matches the description that you've provided, but that is not how it is being displayed on Linux. However there is another character that is "s with a caron". Unicode can be complicated.

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0), the "š" (s with caron) character is actually U+0161 for the lower case and U+0160 for the capital.

This also aligns with this database:

- [Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON' (U+0160)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0160/index.htm)
- [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON' (U+0161)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0161/index.htm)

Comment: Are you sure of the UTF-8 vs. UTF-16 implications of all this?

Comment: @bmargulies My answer does not discuss the encodings of the characters at all. I'm only talking about codepoints, so I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If the character that remains is U+009A, then Linux is not correct. The command is supposed to remove printable characters and leave unprintable ones. U+009A is unprintable, so it should be left in the output. The OP says that Linux is removing this character and OS X is leaving it. If the character that remains is U+0161, then Linux is correct and OS X is incorrect.

Comment: @KenThomases the command is supposed to **d**elete the **c**omplement of printable characters and \n, that is, delete unprintable characters.

Comment: @ninjalj, ah, yes, you're right. Apologies, b4hand.

Comment: Linux tools, including `tr` don't work in terms of codepoints, but bytes. Encodings don't exist for them.

Comment: @KarolS I don't believe that is true unless your locale is the C locale. On my machine, it definitely appears that POSIX character classes are Unicode aware. If you use a naive character range set *it is not* Unicode aware either.

Comment: @b4hand Well, `sed` and `grep` support UTF-8, but they're exceptions, for good reasons. I have `pl_PL.UTF-8` locale and both `tr -d '[:alpha:]'` and `tr -d '[:print:]'` fail to delete accented letters from the input, but they delete ASCII letters just well. If you browse the source of GNU `tr`, you'll notice that it does everything on bytes, not codepoints: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tr.c And so does GNU `cut`: a string of accented letters passed to `cut -c 2` yields a single byte that doesn't represent a character.

Comment: @KarolC Thanks for the source reference. I'll update my answer to state that `tr` truly does not support Unicode.